# Sending email with attachment in unix script fails to send data in the attachment

Tags: shell, unix

I tried to send some attachment in email using unix script . I am able to send the email with attachment but the attachment doesn't contain any data.

```
#!/bin/csh
mailx -s "Sample attachment email" <<EOF
`uuencode myfile.txt`
EOF
```

Answer (score 0):

you should define exit status with uuencode;  0 (EXIT_SUCCESS),
   1 (EXIT_FAILURE)

```
#!/bin/csh
mailx -s "Sample attachment email" root@localhost <<EOF
`uuencode myfile.txt 0`
EOF
```